# Is a continuation created even if there is nothing after an await?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, synchronizationcontext

I was reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) and found this example:

```
public static class DeadlockDemo
{
  private static async Task DelayAsync()
  {
    await Task.Delay(1000);
  }
  // This method causes a deadlock when called in a GUI or ASP.NET context.
  public static void Test()
  {
    // Start the delay.
    var delayTask = DelayAsync();
    // Wait for the delay to complete.
    delayTask.Wait();
  }
}
```

> The root cause of this deadlock is due to the way await handles contexts. By default, when an incomplete Task is awaited, the current “context” is captured and used to resume the method when the Task completes. This “context” is the current SynchronizationContext unless it’s null, in which case it’s the current TaskScheduler. GUI and ASP.NET applications have a SynchronizationContext that permits only one chunk of code to run at a time. When the await completes, it attempts to execute the remainder of the async method within the captured context. But that context already has a thread in it, which is (synchronously) waiting for the async method to complete. They’re each waiting for the other, causing a deadlock.

I understand that if there was code after `await Task.Delay(1000);`, it would be part of the continuation, and that continuation would be running in the same context as `Test()`, and that's how the deadlock would happen.

However, there is no continuation, so how does the deadlock actually happen?

Or, is there an empty continuation that is created? What would be the point in that?

This is the part that is confusing me:

> When the await completes, it attempts to execute the remainder of the
> async method within the captured context.

What is the "remainder of the async method"?

Comment: Nit picking: if there was code after await Task.Delay(1000); that code would run in the context of DelayAsync(), which happens to be the same as Task(), because the method is called synchronously.

Comment: Presumably, "remainder of the async method" could be an empty method that does nothing, but still needs to be called. But I'm not aware if this specific behavior is documented or not.

Comment: @DavidKlempfner `await` says you want to get back to the original sync context. Its behavior isn't affected by whether there's any code after it. If you want to avoid that, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` or return the task directly

Comment: @DavidKlempfner good question!

Comment: "What would be the point in that?" - what would be the point of complicating the compiler to have it behave differently there? The only place you would benefit from lots of machinery not already having been created is if the only `await` in your method is the one at the end and if you didn't want to run any code afterwards, you could have chosen to just ignore whatever it is you chose to `await`.

Comment: And what if thing you await have thrown an exception? `DelayAsync` has two steps - first step it executes `Task.Delay`, second step is executed when `Task.Delay` has completed, and it for example checks if there was an exception. This second step is also "continuation".

Comment: You're the one who *went out of your way* to *intentionally* introduce the continuation, so why are you upset that it was introduced?  If you want to just return the task returned by `Delay` without doing anything else then *just return that task and don't do anything else*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're an `async Task` or `async Task<T>` method, then there's always work to do after the `await` - we need to ensure that any exception produced by the `await`ed task is properly propagated to our own `Task`, or that we pass the appropriate normal return value through.

If we're any kind of `async` method using structures such as `using` which insert compiler-generated code at the end of an otherwise appearing empty epilogue to our method, then we'll be inserting code at the end of the method, even if it doesn't appear in the source.

If we're any normal `async` method that liberally uses `await`s then we'll already have a state machine built and running to execute our method and there's no point in optimizing the "no code after the last await" possibility.

In the *narrow* case that we're an `async void`<sup>1</sup> method that contains a single `await` at the end, then other than some minutiae about where an unhandled exception from a task might be reported, we already had the opportunity to avoid excess code generation by not making the method `async` at all and just ignoring the awaitable.

So there's no reason to try to optimize this situation.

---

<sup>1</sup>We're already in a state of sin at that point anyway.

Comment: *"...there's no point in optimizing the "no code after the last await" possibility."* <== Why? If you have an async method being invoked and awaited 10,000 times in a loop, and you don't optimize the "no code after the last await", you'll end up with 10,000 redundant NO-OP continuations. Unless I am missing something, these continuations could be safely omitted, and save some CPU time.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - people often act as if *every single opportunity for optimizations* should be taken, ignoring the fact that (as here) it only applies in narrow circumstances and there's an opportunity cost that implementing *this* optimization wastes resources that are usefully used elsewhere. You, the code author, already can avoid the continuation by not writing the `await`, as my answer already indicates.

Comment: Damien I don't think that *"we didn't optimize the 'no code after the last await' because you have the option to not use async/await"* is a logical argument. The OP gave an example of an async method having a single `await`, but their question can be generalized for async methods having multiple `await`s. The question really is "why the async state machine generates a continuation after the last `await`, even if there is no code after that?".

Comment: @TheodorZoulias in a generated async state machine, one step begins execution of the task and only on next step ("empty continuation") the result of that task is explored. So it cannot actually be empty, state machine can't just fire and forget that task, the result needs to be explored even if unsused, and exception should be propagated if any.

Comment: @Evk so you say that in order for the async state machine to skip the last empty continuation, it would have to invoke the [`TaskAwaiter.GetResult()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter.getresult) on the current thread, and in case of an exception it should invoke it again on the captured context? This makes sense. It would double the work in case the `await` failed frequently.